# How do you serve dynamically created files in clojure ring server?

Tags: clojure, ring

I have a web server that saves files uploaded by the user to the native filesystem in the `resources` folder. It works fine in development but in production, the files can't be served.

I've tried `wrap-file` and `wrap-resource`, neither works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither `wrap-file` nor `wrap-resource` will work because the dynamic content is served outside of the packaged jar but both middleware expects the item to be in the jar, [as seen in the source.](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/9922384efe27f24473ed4f15dbcd0559ec24327f/ring-core/src/ring/util/response.clj)

Instead, you can actually pass in an input stream of file object directly to the `:body` of the response! Ring will handle it properly and serve it normally, as [seen in the source here](https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/blob/master/ring-servlet/src/ring/util/servlet.clj#L111).

Example code:

```clj
(defn image-handler 
  [request]
  (as-> request r
        (:path-params r)
        (:filename r)
        {:status  200
         :body (io/input-stream (str <your-base-path-here> r))}))
```